# Inflated Odds Ratios in a Mixed Effect Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, sas, odds-ratio

I have a dataset with approximately 40,000 observations, which are dependent, coming from around 30,000 subjects. Most subjects has 1 observation, some have 2, a minority has 3, while 4 is rare. The dependent variable is binary, and I have several independent variables. I have created contingency tables to examine my data descriptively. For one variable (an example, this happened to others too), I got an OR of 3.2 (dependent vs. this independent). Then I ran a logistic regression, and got OR of 3.2. Afterwards I tried a generalized linear mixed model with the subject being a random effect, and I got OR of around 3.2. Then I added to my SAS procedure the instruction to use Laplace approximation, and got OR of over 5, and when I changed to quadrature, I got an OR of over 11! I tried Stata, the default must have been quadrature, because I got 11 again. Only SAS, with the default (likelihood I believe), got OR's similar to the descriptive statistics. I don't believe that 11 is correct. Can anyone please explain to me what could have gone wrong there?

My SAS code was:

```
proc glimmix data = data method = quad;
    class X1;
    model Y = X1 / solution or cl dist = binary;
    random intercept / subject = SubjecID;
run;
```